# DB query builder toArray() laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, query-builder

I'm trying to convert a query to an array with the method `toArray()` but it doesn't work for the query builder. Any ideas for convert it?

Example

```
DB::table('user')->where('name',=,'Jhon')->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

toArray is a model method of Eloquent, so you need to a Eloquent model, try this:

```
 User::where('name', '=', 'Jhon')->get()->toArray();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections

Comment: what if I am forced to use Fluent? I need to read thousands of rows which is not efficient with eloquent!!! that give me maximum execution time while Fluent doesn't

Answer (score 78):

If you prefer to use Query Builder instead of Eloquent here is the solutions

```
$result = DB::table('user')->where('name',=,'Jhon')->get();
```

**First Solution**

```
$array = (array) $result;
```

**Second Solution**

```
$array = get_object_vars($result);
```

**Third Solution**

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
```

Answer (score 13):

**Please note, the option presented below is apparently no longer supported as of Laravel 5.4 (thanks @Alex).**

In Laravel 5.3 and below, there is a method to [set the fetch mode](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L1025-L1034) for select queries.

In this case, it might be more efficient to do:

```
DB::connection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = DB::table('user')->where('name',=,'Jhon')->get();
```

That way, you won't waste time creating objects and then converting them back into arrays.

Comment: The only way to get array of arrays (not array of stdClass objects)

Comment: This [no longer works](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17728) as of Laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 9):

And another solution

```
$objectData = DB::table('user')
    ->select('column1', 'column2')
    ->where('name', '=', 'Jhon')
    ->get();
$arrayData = array_map(function($item) {
    return (array)$item; 
}, $objectData->toArray());
```

It good in case when you need only several columns from entity.

Comment: need to change $objectData->toArray() for it to works

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently on L8 and this is the only way I can find to get this working for a *single* query. You have to globally set an event callback to `FETCH_ASSOC`, then right after the query has ran, set it back to `FETCH_OBJ` (Laravel default).

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\StatementPrepared;

Event::listen(StatementPrepared::class, function ($event) {
        $event->statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    });

$collectionOfArrays = \DB::table('table1')->where(...)->get();

Event::listen(StatementPrepared::class, function ($event) {
        $event->statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    });
```

If you want `FETCH_ASSOC` behaviour throughout, then you can just follow the official upgrade guide and place the first listener in the `AppServiceProvider`.

For my use case, i'm dealing with millions of records, then chunk inserting them into another table via `insert()` as an array. It made more sense to fetch as an array and update as an array, instead of changing the iterable type along the way (performance is key here).

I'm not aware of any performance caveats with this *hack*, as it's served me fine so far. It would made sense for Laravel to add proper support for this, but for now i've just made my own helper class to set and revert around the queries I need it to.

Answer (score 1):

`User::where('name','Jhon')->get()->toArray();`

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Tested in **Laravel 5.6**

The fastest and simple way is just to use json_decode (No need to use json_encode), example:

```
$records = DB::table('user')->where('name',=,'Jhon')->get();

echo json_decode($records,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Query Builder To Array work a round**

`toArray()` For Eloquent ORM:

```
// Using Eloquent ORM
$users = User::where('name', '=', 'Jhon')->get()->toArray();
```

`toArray()` For Query Builder:

```
// Using Query Builder
$data = DB::table('user')->where('name', '=', 'Jhon')->get();
$users = collect($data)->map(function($x){ return (array)$x; })->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User::where("fk_role_id",3)->pluck('id')->toArray()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is using laravel toArray function itself:

```
    $result = array_map(function ($value) {
        return $value instanceof Arrayable ? $value->toArray() : $value;
    }, $result);
```

Comment: Objects inside the result set are instances of `stdClass` so `$value->toArray()` won't work and this code will do nothing to `$result`

Answer (score -2):

You can do this using the query builder. Just use SELECT instead of TABLE and GET.

```
DB::select('select * from user where name = ?',['Jhon']);
```

Notes:
 1. Multiple question marks are allowed.
 2. The second parameter must be an array, even if there is only one parameter.
 3. Laravel will automatically clean parameters, so you don't have to.

Further info here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#running-queries

Hmmmmmm, turns out that still returns a standard class for me when I don't use a where clause. I found this helped:

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
print_r(get_object_vars($result));
}
```

However, get_object_vars isn't recursive, so don't use it on $results.

Answer (score -3):

try this one

```
DB::table('user')->where('name','Jhon')->get();
```

just remove the "=" sign . . . .because you are trying to array just the name 'jhon' . . . . . . . .I hope it's help you . .

Comment: This approach can only get Collection. Not array. The question is asking about toArray()