# Need array instead of object in laravel using raw Query like DB::select("SELECT * FROM table");

Tags: laravel

In laravel when i use `DB::select("SELECT * FROM table");` 
It return a object,but i need a array. 
So how can i get a array instead of object?

example:

```
$data = DB::select("SELECT * FROM table");
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [DB query builder toArray() laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776656/db-query-builder-toarray-laravel-4)

Comment: $data itself is an array so $data could not be converted to an array while looping foreach over $data and then converting object to array will throw error take a look at the following question answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022544/can-i-use-stdclass-like-an-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Try this one.

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$values=\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select("select * from  your_table");
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
var_dump($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually returns an array of objects. To make an individual object to be an array just cast it. For example: `(array)$data[0]`

Comment: I need a two dimension array not object

Comment: Can you explain how you can get a two dimensional array by doing `SELECT *` when in fact you might get, say 10 records back?

Comment: i need a method which return a full array instead of object?

Comment: Note: Casting $data to an array is not relevant as it as already an array and casting will not affect it's members. Each of them has to be cast individually or json_encode/json_decode combination has to be used